# IntelliSense does not work for jquery custom Plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, intellisense

I have created a jQuery plugin and included it from a separate `js` file.
In my .cshtml file, I successfully call a custom method from my plugin and get output.

The problem is that I can't get the function suggested when using my IDE (Visual Studio 2017).

I'd expect IntelliSense to suggest `bindItems` after tiping `$ddl.`,
but it doesn't.

```js
(function ($) {

    $.fn.bindItems= function (option1,option2) {
      //adding items in ddl here;
    }

}(jQuery));
```

```html
  <select id="ddltest" class="dropdownclass" name="drpSpendChartId"> 
  </select>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
 
    BindDDL();

});

    function BindDDL() {
        var $ddl = $("#ddltest");
        $ddl.bindItems('my', 'Plugin'); //here when dot(.) pressed after '$ddl' the 'bindItems' method does not list under intelligence dropdown list.
    }

</script>
```

Comment: The keypress listener is in your plugin?

Comment: thanks @Sampgun, I have no idea abut keypress listener can you please give me any link to check get more information.

Comment: Sorry but I understood your question just now!! You're saying that your IDE is not suggesting "bindItems" when you're typing!
Can you please tell which editor are you using?

Comment: yes @Sampgun, I am using visual studio 2017

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: yes, @Sampgun I am trying to implement second approach.